# defu__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ is not a function nuxt auth

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I keep getting the error `defu__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ is not a function` when running nuxt auth v5 while using [this](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup) guide from the official documentation. Has anyone else ever encountered that problem? How did you solve it?

PS: It only appears when I set the `strategies` options

Comment: Getting the same error after upgrading `@nuxtjs/tailwind` from 5.0.4 to 5.1.2. I have opened bug #493 on GitHub: https://github.com/nuxt-community/tailwindcss-module/issues/493

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem about the auth strategies.
I've solved it by installing defu in version 5.0.1.

```
yarn add defu@5.0.1
```